# How to get all applications associated to a specific file extension in windows?

Tags: c++, windows

I want to get a list of applications associated to a specific file extension such as '.txt'.

There are some information storing in HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT, but I don't want to access it directly.

I think it may have a solution to get the executable path and there default icons.
Thanks for all your help.

Comment: I can't say for sure, but perhaps http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776320(v=vs.85).aspx would help somewhat.

Comment: Agreed - if you don't want to query the registry directly you should ask the shell.

Comment: Thank you @chris, it's really helpful!  And I find the related api SHAssocEnumHandlers may work fine. Hope it can give some information to someone who has the same question.