# How to get command line of windows "open with .." function?

Tags: c++, windows, msdn

I previously asked a question that is about how to get windows "open with.." application list.
Here's [a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18299144/how-to-get-all-applications-associated-to-a-specific-file-extension-in-windows) to that question.

We can use `SHAssocEnumHandlers` interface to get the file association with specific file extension, ex `.png`

Then use IAssocHandler and can retrieves the full path and file name of the executable file associated with the file type(`.png`). ex:`['Paint': 'C:\\Windows\\system32\\mspaint.exe', ...]`

But I want to get the command line of executing mspaint.exe with a given image.
Like this~ `"%systemroot%\system32\mspaint.exe" "%1"`

Is there another msdn api could help us to get the "open with.." command? 
I think it should have, since windows XP already have this ability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `AssocQueryString(..., ASSOCSTR_COMMAND, ...);`

Example:

```
TCHAR commandline[1024];
DWORD size = ARRAYSIZE(commandline);
AssocQueryString(0, ASSOCSTR_COMMAND, _T(".txt"), 0, commandline, &size);
```

Answer (score 1):

There is the `SHOpenWithDialog` function.

[Link to SHOpenWithDialog on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762234%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

However, you can't use this to retrieve the selected program.  You can only use it to invoke the "Open With" behaviour and eventually open the file (if `OAIF_EXEC` is set).  If that's all you're interested in, then try it out:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <Shlobj.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "Shell32.lib")

int main()
{
    OPENASINFO info = { 0 };
    info.pcszFile = L"C:\\Temp\\SomeFile.png";
    info.pcszClass = NULL;
    info.oaifInFlags = OAIF_ALLOW_REGISTRATION | OAIF_EXEC;
    SHOpenWithDialog(NULL, &info);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for you suggestion. I still want to get command line, since I want to implement my own open with menu.

Comment: Perhaps there's something I'm missing from your question then.  You said that you *can* retrieve the full path of the executable.  To construct the commandline, you just add the target file as the first parameter.  Windows programs expect this, and if they require other parameters when invoked this way, they will provide a wrapper executable which doesn't.