# How to get user choice from "Open With" dialog in C#?

Tags: c#, windows, winapi, file-association

Using C#, how can I prompt the "open with" dialog ([this one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wSE2g.png)) for a file and receive the user choice? It can be either the progid or command line.

I know how to open this dialog (SHOpenWithDialog or RunDll32), but can't seem to find a way to get the program the user selected.

Comment: Are you running in Windows10 ?

Comment: I would like it to work on Windows 7 or newer (so 10 is included)

Comment: You can't get the app - this is a 'handoff' routine - you have asked to open the file/URL, and the OS takes care of it from there.

Comment: There are a lot of answers about how to call this dialog (as you mentioned). But the way this is done, it seems there is no return value. Calling this dialog means that it _will start_ the selected application, but never return the selection to you. So you might have to re-develop it. The application it shows can surely be read from registry.

Comment: The [answer to this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18326507/how-to-get-command-line-of-windows-open-with-function) may help in constructing the dialog manually if you want more control, though.